# Cocoa application built under OS X 10.6 crashes on OS X 10.7

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

My Cocoa application works fine on Mac OS X 10.6, however if I try to run it under 10.7, it crashes with the following stack trace:

```
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libicucore.A.dylib              0x9a860a07 0x9a7df000 + 530951
1   libicucore.A.dylib              0x9a861959 0x9a7df000 + 534873
2   libicucore.A.dylib              0x9a7e26fc uloc_canonicalize + 38
3   libicucore.A.dylib              0x9a7e5179 uloc_minimizeSubtags + 71
4   libicucore.A.dylib              0x9a7e4dda icu::Calendar::setWeekData(icu::Locale const&, char const*, UErrorCode&) + 242
5   libicucore.A.dylib              0x9a7e4cd7 icu::Calendar::Calendar(icu::TimeZone*, icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 161
6   libicucore.A.dylib              0x9a7e2c73 icu::GregorianCalendar::GregorianCalendar(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 49
7   libicucore.A.dylib              0x9a7e2248 icu::Calendar::createInstance(icu::TimeZone*, icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 762
8   libicucore.A.dylib              0x9a7dfa8a ucal_open + 352
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9b2eb41e __CFCalendarCreateUCalendar + 430
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9b2eb1a9 CFCalendarCreateWithIdentifier + 537
```

Can you please tell me, if it possible to fix the problem without rebuilding application under 10.7? Maybe I should somehow statically link Cocoa libraries and frameworks I'm using?

Please help!

Comment: Post the code that is causing the crash if possible, also the console log with the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was related to NSLog class, which appears to be non-thread-safe in 10.7 for some stupid reason...

Comment: File a bug report.  Make sure to include a code sample to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I got this crash in NSLog on the main thread, and no other threads appear to be using NSLog or anything involving calendars.

Answer (score 1):

Without rebuilding your whole program, you may have to check the version of certain libraries. If the system library changed from 10.6 to 10.7 then some of your call may need to be updated.

I don't know which dependencies you have, but maybe try to see if you have the latest version for your OSX 10.7

EDIT : I don't know if the library that contain the object calendar is something you built or not, but I would start by looking at its dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, Rob... I'm using Cocoa, QuartzCore, OpenAL, OpenGL, IOKit, AppKit & Foundation frameworks from 10.6 SDK...